# Visual FoxPro (9.0) issue on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: windows, foxpro

We have been running a Visual FoxPro (version 9) application on a Server under Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Operating system for a number of years now. We are now trying to migrate it to a different Server running under Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 and the application crashes. The problem occurs when it is trying to create HTML files from the FoxPro reports it has just created. To do this is uses the system variable _ReportOutput and aborts with the message “ox is not an object”. The application resides on the Network in a directory accessible to both Servers. Since hitting this problem I have changed the program to use the Htmllistener class within _ReportListener and get the same problem (works on one not on the other (R2)). Wait windows have been inserted to gain additional information but they only show that the object has not been created returning a data type of .Logical. It appears to me the problem is with the R2 version of the operating system, has anybody any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed ReportOutput.APP in the same folder as the application?

Comment: @DaveTupper, additionally, the ReportPreview.App.

Comment: Thanks but yes, the folder tha App is run from is Networked and accessible to both Servers.